# Change Background Color of MvxItemTemplate?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, itemtemplate

How does one change the Background Color of an MvxItemTemplate?

I can change the Background of the MvxListView, but that changes the background of all the elements.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/favoritesList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/template_screen"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FavoritesGroupedList; ItemClick ScreenSelectedCommand; ItemLongClick ShowUnFavoriteCommand" />
```

If I place `BackgroundColor BlackOrBlueColor(IsUnFavorite)` in the local:MvxBind for the ListView, it works.  I tried to place the Binding in my template:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/screenIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor BlackOrBlueColor(IsUnFavorite)"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/screenText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the MvxItemTemplate background color, but you can change the background color of the root layout inside the item template:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor BlackOrBlueColor(IsUnFavorite)">
```

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't change the background color.  I have a list and I want the user to be able to select multiple items for deletion.  If the item is contained in the list of items to possibly be removed I want it to be highlighted so the user knows what they're deleting.  Does this add any clarification?

Comment: You need to create a ColorStateList: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html